# Rasberry pi Zero W USB Hub Driver?

Tags: pi-zero-w, usb-hub

Is it mandatory to use powered USB hub with pi-zero-w...?
I've two good quality USB Hub, that works just fine with my windows PC.

**But, when I connect to the Pi, it supports only "one Device".**
While, installing OS with NOOB, I've to change Keyboard & mouse, again and again...
**Is there any USB driver I've to install?**

Because, many forum member said, that, a unpowered USB Hub is working just like charm...

> ***Additional info:*** Sometime the mouse LED stays off, after some blink.
>   But, While working with Kboard, then connect the mouse, Mouse stays
>   lighten up, but does not work...

Here, a screenshot from PC with, mouse, flash drive, keyboard,
[image: Power consumption]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked my both USB-Hub this time, and the problem is solved,
The "Amkette" one, drives the 3 devices smoothly...

**I think the other one only supports Windows.
So, I suggest to new/beginners to check the USB-Hub supported OS.**
(and ignore cheap USB-Hub)

Many users having problem with USB-hub, maybe this'll solve their issue...

Thank you anyway... :)

Answer (score 1):

USB requires power. That has to come from somewhere, either from the Pi, the hub or the USB device.

If you look at your connected devices, they require around 350 mA. The Pi zerro requires 150 mA  for "typical bare board activity". That means that your power supply must be at least 500 mA. The Pi-FAQ suggests using more that twice that (1.2A).

From your additional info, I get the impression that your 5v supply is less that the 500mA that we just calulated.

Unless you have a very exotic mouse or keyboard, there should not be any need for additional drivers on NOOB.

Comment: Now, I'm trying only Kboard and Mouse on pi... And powering the pi with a 2A powerbank... I'll give it try with 2A adapter...